# Explicitly finding hyperbolic geodesics given a complex structure (punctured complex plane)

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, geometry, surfaces

I am looking to figure out how to find hyperbolic geodesics on the complex plane with punctures. I know that the punctured plane is a hyperbolic surface (for >=3 punctures, as well as infinitely many punctures). However, I'm not sure how this works explicitly, and furthermore how the hyperbolic structure relates to the complex structure.

I would appreciate any sources and ideas. Many thanks!

Comment: Explicit uniformization is unknown once you have complex plane with more than 3 punctures.

Comment: Thank you! Is it that no one has found an explicit uniformization or that we know we cannot find an explicit uniformization (or that we know it's a really, really hard problem)?

Comment: It is a really hard problem (called "accessory parameters problem") going back to Poincare.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks so much!!!